# What is the runtime class of Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I need to know the runtime class of `Arrays.asList()`.

So when i do this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
logger.info(list.getClass()); // ==> class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
```

The log shows: **class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList** .

Some search for,  **java.util.Arrays$ArrayList**:

> is a nested class inside the **Arrays** class that implements the **List** interface. This implementation has a fixed length and is backed by an array.

But i do not find the runtime class of it, to do this alt when for exemple: **List args = Arrays.asList("one", "two")**

```
public Object register(Object args) {

       if(args.getClass().equals(java.util.Arrays.class)) {
            //do something
            // don't work
            return "";
       }
       if(args.getClass().equals(ArrayList.class)) {
            //do something
            // don't work
            return "";
       }
       //other Alt statement code
       return "";
}
```

I have no idea how to do the comparaison.

Comment: Why do you *need* to know it? It's an implementation detail, and you shouldn't depend on it for your program correctness.

Comment: @chrylis, caus the param 'args' can be a String or Arrays.asList() and the implementation of the register method depends of the runtime class of the this param

Comment: Then your register method is broken in multiple ways: You should have multiple compile-time overloads, not accept `Object`, and you should not distinguish between the specific list type used by `asList()` and any general `List<String>`.

Comment: @chrylis the register(Object args) method implemnts a Delegate pattern and the body of this method process of multiple alternative if(args.getclass().equals(String.class)){ // ..}.... if(args.getClass().equals(Integer.class)){//... }.... if(args.getClass().equals(java.util.Arrays$ArrayList)) { //.....}